# Parsing query array with request and receiving with express

Tags: node.js, express, get, request

I have an issue sending and receiving query params with express and request.

Request side:

```
const request = require('request');
request({url: 'http://localhost', json: true, qs: {id: [1,2,3,4]}})
```

Request sends a request like that to my server:

```
http://localhost/?id%5B0%5D=1&id%5B1%5D=2&id%5B2%5D=3&id%5B3%5D=4
```

Then when I receive my result using express

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.query);
})
```

I have

```
{id: {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}}
```

I would like to have

```
{id: [1,2,3,4]}
```

If I manually send a request using this url it works

```
http://localhost/?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4
```

So I do not understand if the error comes from `request` witch have issues parsing my array or `express` having problems parsing my query

Comment: If you want to get an array try to send the data in the following format: `{ 'qs[]': [1,2,3,4] }`.

Comment: You can also use the option ```useQuerystring: true,``` to stringify the query parameters as ```?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in express (qs), there is a limit to the element number 20.

https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2661

Answer (score 0):

This has to with encoding and decoding of the urls, when you decode the url that doesn't work you'd get:

```
http://localhost/?id[0]=1&id[1]=2&id[2]=3&id[3]=4
```

Which the program treats them as indexes of the object. `%5B` equals to `[` and `%5D` equals to `]` in an encoded syntax. You can't get that output with this sort of a link as I see your code in the back-end since they're treated like indexes of the object.

This url works because they are not referred to any indexes.

```
http://localhost/?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4
```

You can encode and decode urls from [this link.](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/)

Comment: I know, is there a way to say request to parse like that: `http://localhost/?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4`

Comment: try to change the `qs` to plain `{}` let me see what it returns @Ajouve

Comment: very good question, then I think you should not specify the `[index]`s because when you do, it apparently converts to an object from an array. when you don't specify the `[]` the indexes become in order. I think just go with the one that runs. @Ajouve

Comment: I am not specifying the index, `request` does it automatically, it transforms an object like that `{id: ['a', 'b']}` into `id[0]=a&id[1]=b` and not `id=a&id=b`. I am just trying to find a way to have my query well parsed

Comment: what do you get when you do `{id: null}` or `{id: undefined}` @Ajouve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154459/discussion-between-ajouve-and-turmuka).